# NFS Datastore for Vmware high IO

Tags: storage, nfs, vmware-vsphere, network-attached-storage

Currently we have many 1U data-stores that are running a 10Gbps copper. Each box pretty much saturates its line (700gbps-900Gbps sustained) they all have 300GB SAS drives x8 in a raid 10 so about 1 TB total per box. (inherited this setup)

We need more storage and less rack space so the 10 servers are being removed and I am looking to put 2-2U's in their place. I am being asked to increase storage to 40TB raw and my question is related to new hardware.

If I get 2U or 4U server that has 40tb raw raid 10 each with 100GbE I assume I would still be limited by the 12Gbps raid controller. Each 2u will have 24 10k 2.4TB SAS drives.

Am I better off scaling to more servers like the current setup and not saving rack space? Or is there a way to consolidate these 10 1U servers into something that can handle 85-100Gbps sustained and not have a bottleneck by the raid controller?

Comment: This is an architecture question that's pretty thin on actual requirements. Can you provide better detail?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need multiple RAID controllers to make that happen. Look at the IOPS load on your current server, and figure out how much IOPS you actually need, then work with your vendor to get servers that can handle the IO load.

But, if you're running at 9000 Mbps sustained your NICs are the bottleneck. If your application can handle it, I'd suggest moving to NIC teaming, maybe 40 Gbps NICs as well, 100 Gbps NICs are terribly expensive compared to multiple 40 Gbps NICs.

But, as I said, work with your vendor to get what you need, the setup you're describing is rather expensive to begin with, so any vendor will be happy to help you size your servers properly.